# in php how to output image to position that I want

Tags: php

I have the following piece of code. All I want is to echo image inside the td (where it says insert image here). Any idea how to do this?

```
<?php

$personal_1 = mysql_query("SELECT `user_id`, `name`, `surname`, `profile` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`='{$row['user']}' ");

while ($run_personal_1= mysql_fetch_assoc($personal_1)) {

    $comment_user_id = $run_personal_1['user_id'];
    $comment_user_name = $run_personal_1['name'];
    $comment_user_surname = $run_personal_1['surname'];
    $comment_user_profile = $run_personal_1['profile'];

  $profile_data     = user_data($comment_user_id,'name','surname','email','profile');

  if(!($profile_data['profile']==NULL)){
    echo '<img src="', $profile_data['profile'], '" alt="' ,  '  Profile Image not yet ready!  ">'; 
  }else     
    echo'<img src="img/photo.jpg"/>'; 
}


$comments .= "<table border='1'> <td>   insert image here   </td> <td> $comment_user_surname   $comment_user_name </td></table>"; 
?>
```

I would like to place image in position "insert image here". Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Your question is probably being downvoted because this is such a basic thing to understand in PHP. Don't be discouraged by it. Keep working at it and pay attention to the good answers and soon you'll be asking questions that get upvoted. :-)

Comment: thanks for your understanding friend...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So what's tough in that? Just assign the image path to to a variable and use that variable where you want to..

```
if(!($profile_data['profile']==NULL)){
    $path_img = '<img src="'.$profile_data['profile'].'" alt="'.'  Profile Image not yet ready!  ">'; 
  }else     
    $path_img ='<img src="img/photo.jpg"/>'; 
}


$comments .= "<table border='1'> <td>   $path_img   </td> <td> $comment_user_surname   $comment_user_name </td></table>";
```

In the above code, am storing the path in `$path_img` and than am using at the place where you want your image to be rendered.

Comment: get  syntax error, unexpected ',' in line: $path_img = '<img src="', $profile_data['profile'], '" alt="' ,  '  Profile Image not yet ready!  ">';

Comment: @user2491321 use `.` instead of a `,`

Comment: thank you so much....finally works

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there.

```
  if(!($profile_data['profile']==NULL)){
    $img= '<img src="', $profile_data['profile']. '" alt="' .  '  Profile Image not yet ready!  ">'; 
  }else     
    $img='<img src="img/photo.jpg"/>'; 
}


$comments .= "<table border='1'> <td>".$img."</td>
```

Comment: always get Undefined variable when using this variable inside td.

Comment: Then your "while" loop is not running. Check the conditions that are supposed to initiate that loop and troubleshoot backward from there. That is, check your DB result. It might be empty. While you're at it, please look into PDO instead of "mysql_". You'll be glad you did!

Comment: that is what I thought, but consider that it prints successfully $comment_user_name and $comment_user_surname but not the image.

Comment: When you had the `echo` instead of the `$img=` did one or the other get echoed to the browser?